# convert GET request that's array of paths to blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, response, get-request

My response is array of paths (for images) and looks something like:

```
[
    "path_of_img1",
    "path_of_img2",
    "path_of_img3"
]
```

Using Material-UI I want to display those images in `<ImageList>`

As far as I know for images, the paths have to be turned into blobs so that images get loaded on the web.

So here's my issue:

How to turn the response that looks array of paths into blobs

here's my get request code

```
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:4000/photographers/portfolio/${id}`
        // , {responseType: "blob",}
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        // const json = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, res.data));
        // console.log("json", json);

        let url = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
          url.push(window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data[i]])));
        }
        //const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
        setPortfolio(url);
        console.log("url", url);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

the output of  `console.log("url", url);`
is

```
url (3) ['blob:http://localhost:3000/b6b132a3-f27d-468f-915c-d7d3d8795dcc',
 'blob:http://localhost:3000/dddcb681-4df7-426b-bd39-8b73e4cacd2e', 
'blob:http://localhost:3000/ac77eccc-53f0-4533-b17e-adea723983e7']
```

I commented the header `{responseType: "blob",}` out, as it formed a single blob that doesn't work

code for `<ImageList>` is

```
              {portfolio.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <ImageListItem key={item}>
                    <img src={item} alt={"porfolio"} />
                  </ImageListItem>
                );
              })}
            </ImageList>
```

**edit after removing window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(**
in .push

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uG7g.png)

**context:** API returns multiple full paths in an array, as i have uploaded multiple images for that user, so i want to display those images on his profile

Comment: No need to return blob. If you are receiving full path then it will work for sure. Just remove everything inside the push and it will work
`url.push(res.data[i])`

Comment: But don't i need objURL so that the path of image gets converted into URL and the browser understands it's an image to be displayed?

Comment: output of the URL is now array of arrays of paths
so it's not what i want

Comment: if the API is returning full path for example: `http://localhost:3000/assets/public/image.jpg` then you do not need to convert. If API returning anything else then you should make changes in you API and make sure you return full path. But no need to this stuff in front end.

Comment: Please post the output

Comment: url (3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]

inside each Array(1) is the path